Why dart:convert :: json.encoder turns everything into a string?
I am trying to send an HTTP PUT request to FastAPI backend from flutter code. I jsonify the data before I put into the request body. Here are my data classes:
class ListeningHistory {
  final String userId;
  List<BareMinPost> podcasts;

  ListeningHistory({required this.userId, required this.podcasts});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    podcasts = []; // for simplicity's sake
    return {'user_id': userId, 'podcasts': jsonEncode(podcasts)};
  }

Please note that I intentionally replaced the actual podcasts with an empty array above for the sake of simplicity for this example.
class BareMinPost {
  final String title;
  final String publishedDate;
  final int pausedAt;

  BareMinPost({
    required this.title,
    required this.publishedDate,
    required this.pausedAt,
  });

  BareMinPost.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : title = json['title'] as String,
        publishedDate = json['publishedDate'] as String,
        pausedAt = json['pausedAt'] as int;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {'title': title, 'publishedDate': publishedDate, 'pausedAt': pausedAt};

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "BareMinPost - title: $title   publishedDate: $publishedDate   puasedAt: $pausedAt";
  }
}

I use the following piece of code to json encode the data:
    import 'dart:convert';
...
    ListeningHistory hist = ListeningHistory(
        userId: "$userId", podcasts: previouslyListenedTo);
    String reqBody = json.encode(hist);
    dualLog(logger, '------------------->>>>-----$reqBody');

log line prints out as follows:
------------------->>>>-----{"user_id":"org.couchdb.users:alp","podcasts":"[]"}

Please note the double quotes around the array at the end. These, I believe should not be there but they are for some reason.
And eventually when I send this request the fastapi server, it complains as follows:
ERROR: {"detail":[{"type":"list_type","loc":["body","podcasts"],"msg":"Input should be a valid list","input":"[]"}]}

What am I missing here ?

Looking at the method toJson of your class ListeningHistory that is exactly the output I would expect.

thanks for the comment. but I didn't quite understand what you meant. if you meant that I had made a mistake in my toJson implementation in ListeningHistory class, mind elaborating a bit? @DanR

I meant to add that jsonEncode(podcasts) returns the String "[ ]".

but having a [ ] as a string is causing a problem on the server side. How can I remove those double quotes ? any ideas ?

Instead of a String you need to return an object of type List. The function jsonEncode (which is just an alias of json.encode) is called later to create the String reqBody.

Thanks, that was the issue. if you send your last comment as an answer, I will gladly accept it. Thanks much. I think I over analyzed it and messed up there. @DanR

I expanded the comment and included an example:
import 'dart:convert' show JsonUnsupportedObjectError, jsonEncode, jsonDecode;

class BareMinPost {
  BareMinPost({required this.title});
  final String title;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {'title': title};

  factory BareMinPost.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    // Validate input
    if (json
        case {
          'title': String title,
        }) {
      return BareMinPost(title: title);
    } else {
      throw JsonUnsupportedObjectError(json,
          cause: 'BareMinPost: Json validation failed');
    }
  }
}

class ListeningHistory {
  final String userId;
  List<BareMinPost> podcasts;

  ListeningHistory({required this.userId, required this.podcasts});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'user_id': userId,
      'podcasts': podcasts
          .map(
            (e) => e.toJson(),
          )
          .toList()
    };
  }

  factory ListeningHistory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    // Validate input
    if (json
        case {
          'user_id': String userId,
          'podcasts': List podcasts,
        }) {
      return ListeningHistory(
        userId: userId,
        podcasts: podcasts.map((e) => BareMinPost.fromJson(e)).toList(),
      );
    } else {
      throw JsonUnsupportedObjectError(json,
          cause: 'ListeningHistory: Json validation failed');
    }
  }
}

Usage:
void main(List<String> args) {
  final history = ListeningHistory(userId: 'json1997', podcasts: [
    BareMinPost(title: 'Song A'),
    BareMinPost(title: 'Song B'),
  ]);

  // Encoding
  print('Encoding: ...');
  print(
    history.toJson(),
  ); // Prints: {user_id: json1997, podcasts: [{title: Song A}, {title: Song B}]}
  final jsonString = jsonEncode(history.toJson());
  print(
    jsonString,
  ); // Prints: {"user_id":"json1997","podcasts":[{"title":"Song A"},{"title":"Song B"}]}

  // Decoding
  print('\nDecoding ...');
  final jsonMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);
  print(jsonMap);
  final historyClone = ListeningHistory.fromJson(jsonMap);
}

The console output is listed below:
Encoding: ...
{user_id: json1997, podcasts: [{title: Song A}, {title: Song B}]}
{"user_id":"json1997","podcasts":[{"title":"Song A"},{"title":"Song B"}]}

Decoding ...
{user_id: json1997, podcasts: [{title: Song A}, {title: Song B}]}

